# Is `dpkg --contents` unable to handle SIGPIPE?

Tags: shell, dpkg

I noticed a weird antipattern in some CI scripts I've taken over, which basically boils down to this code checking whether a particular file is present in a package:

```bsh
dpkg --contents some.deb > contents.txt
grep --quiet foo contents.txt
```

I tried the obvious refactor of `dpkg --contents some.deb | grep --quiet foo`, but I keep getting this error:

> dpkg-deb: error: tar subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)

From some more investigation, this is definitely a timing issue. If I use a regex which matches *early* in the input stream I get the error, but if I use a regex which specifically matches a late line it succeeds.

The most obvious conclusion is that `dpkg` (or possibly `tar`) does something wrong with SIGPIPE. Is this a known issue?

Platform:

```
# lsb_release --all
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
# dpkg --version
Debian 'dpkg' package management program version 1.19.0.5 (amd64).
This is free software; see the GNU General Public License version 2 or
later for copying conditions. There is NO warranty.
# tar --version
tar (GNU tar) 1.29
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by John Gilmore and Jay Fenlason.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`dpkg` uses `tar` to list the package contents. When `tar` can’t process an archive in full, it indicates an error, and that’s what `dpkg` is reporting. Both commands expect that an inability to complete their task is an error, and act accordingly.

You can avoid this by ensuring that `grep` reads all its input before exiting:

```
| grep foo > /dev/null
```

(instead of `-q`, which exits as soon as it matches).

Comment: A SIGPIPE is a normal situation though. I think this must be the first time I've encountered a commonly available tool which considers this an error.

Comment: A `SIGPIPE` isn’t a normal situation, it’s just that in most cases you don’t see it since the default shell handling is to only consider the last command’s result. `dpkg` and `tar` are perhaps slightly unusual in that they print an error message before exiting on `SIGPIPE`; but the default on `SIGPIPE` is to exit with code 141 (128 + `SIGPIPE`), indicating failure.

Comment: Compare `(/bin/echo Hello; /bin/printf "%s\n" {1..100000}; echo $? 1>&2; /bin/echo world; echo $? 1>&2) | grep -q Hello` and `(/bin/echo Hello; /bin/printf "%s\n" {1..100000}; echo $? 1>&2; /bin/echo world; echo $? 1>&2) | grep -q world`.

Comment: Or `/usr/bin/printf`, depending on your distribution.

Comment: Or, perhaps even more interesting, try `(trap 'echo pipe error 1>&2' SIGPIPE; echo Hello; printf "%s\n" {1..100000}; echo a:$? 1>&2; echo world; echo b:$? 1>&2) | grep -q Hello` using `bash` with or without the `trap` command, and under one of the options `set -o pipefail` and `set +o pipefail`.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a command which will soak up the output of `dpkg` before
passing it all to `grep`, without generating an error on SIGPIPE. `perl` is such a command:

```
dpkg --contents some.deb | perl -0777 -pe1 | grep --quiet foo
```

The `perl` options mean:

- `-0777` slurp the entire input into one "line"
- `-p` read each "line" from stdin and print it to stdout
- `-e1` evaluate the given expression (`1`) for every input "line".

Comment: Of course `-0777` means "slurp up everyting" in perl, I mean, why wouldn't it?